# Access key issue with aws-sdk S3 in production environment (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using the AWS-SDK in order to storage my images from my webapp. Also, I am using Javascript and multer in order to make the manage of the process. When I call the API from my localhost (my local computer) in order to do my tests, all works fine. But when I upload my project to a Digital Ocean droplet, it always says the following error:

```
The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

I have set my environment access key and the secret key in the file `/etc/environment` and when I execute the command `printenv`, I can see the variables listed.

I am using the same variables both in my local computer and in the server. Why AWS reject my request?

In advance thanks. Here is my code:

```
var s3 = new aws.S3({
  region: 'us-west-2',
  accessKeyId: config.aws.accessKey,
  secretAccessKey: config.aws.secretKey
})

var storage = multerS3({
  s3: s3,
  bucket: 'pos-lisa',
  acl: 'public-read',
  metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname})
  },
  key: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + fileExt(file.originalname))
  }
})
```

Comment: If the access/secret keys are in your environment, then you don't need to explicitly provide them to the S3 constructor. The SDK will retrieve the credentials as needed. Change your S3 constructor to simply pass in the target region.

Comment: @jarmod thanks for your answer. I tried what you suggest, but now I am getting "missing credentials". I this is mandatory to put them in the S3 constructor

Comment: How are you populating config.aws? Also, try this gist to see which credentials the AWS SDK thinks are in your environment/config: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/64429653df3a8160b208f2d2d543d0ca

Comment: @jarmod With that gist, you give me a clue, because when I make the 'console.log', it prints the access key with quotes, so I think that is the problem, but I tried to remove the quotes without success, can you tell me how can I set the environment variables without quotes? I tried like this: AWS_ACCESS_KEY = MYKEYIWWM, but it still prints the variable with quotes

Comment: @jarmod you gave me the main clue. I have removed the single quotes of the variable through javascript and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot